# Arduino LCD changing contrast only makes black boxes less readable i.e. less in contrast

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I have seen similar issues posted here but none match my problem exactly.

I have a starter kit and a 16x2 LCD screen that only shows black boxes in the top row using the following code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {

}
```

All tutorials use a potentiometer to change the contrast but I don't have one so I decided to use chain several resistors. When doing so, the contrast indeed changes, but it changes as a whole. The black boxes become less readable i.e. less in contrast (more vague) but stay completely black.

Just to make sure, I have a cable from the + tray (with 5v) to the VDD port and - tray (with GND) to the VSS port. The K port is on the - tray as well and the A is with a 220 ohm resistor on the + tray.

I have tried no, 3k, 4k, 3220, 10k and 100k ohm on the v0 port to change the contrast.

What could be wrong? Any help is appreciated.

## Edit photo:

[image]

Comment: Black boxes mean the screen isn't being initialized. Check your wiring.

Comment: @Majenko I checked it at least 2 times. Either a cable is faulty, I forgot code or my LCD is broken. Can't think of another reason at this point.

Comment: Maybe you could show us your wiring and we can check it for you?

Comment: @Majenko photo or provide an overview in my question? Following all cables might be a bit messy I fear.

Comment: Photo. It's hard to see what you have done from test alone.

Comment: @Majenko take a look. I hope it's clear enough

Comment: That is almost impossible to follow. Don't you have some more varied colours of wires? Or separate them out a bit so they can be followed manually?

Comment: @Majenko I feared so. I do not have that many colors unfortunately. It's the setup shown in this video minus the potentiometer (I used 3 chained 1k resistors): https://youtu.be/Mr9FQKcrGpA?t=3m45s

Comment: You have your polarities round the wrong way. `VDD` and `A` (for 'anode') should be positive/5V; `VSS` and `K` (for 'kathode') are Ground. As you have a backlight, I suspect you have at least `A` and `K` the right way round, but you have `Vss/Vdd` switched.

Comment: @CharlieHanson Sorry my bad, A was actually in the + tray and the K in the - tray. Mixed them up in the text. VSS is in the - tray as well like in the text and VDD in the +.

Comment: Great, now all you have to do is re-read my comment and find the *other* mistake you are still making.

Comment: @CharlieHanson, K and VSS in the - tray which is connected to ground, VDD and A in the + tray. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing from that comment, but the text in the question is still incorrect. The quality of the photo is so bad that it's very tough to know if it's a typo or actual incorrect wiring. Always check, check, then check again.

Comment: Please post the photo in the question, not a link off-site. There is an icon for adding photos to questions.